# Which glyph(s) should be used to represent the word 'numero': N°, n°, or №?

Tags: orthographe, typographie, énumération

Which is the most correct/proper way to represent the word *numero* in metropolitan, standard written French? I have seen all 4 of the following in use:

№ (NUMERO SIGN U+2116)?

N° (an always capitalised 'N' followed by DEGREE SIGN U+00B0)?

n° (a lowercase 'n', except at the start of sentences, followed by DEGREE SIGN U+00B0)?

No. (the letters 'n' and 'o' followed by a full stop; I have seen both capitalised and non-capitalised permutations)

Answer (score 5):

Using the degree sign is often done because it is directly available on a French (AZERTY) keyboard. That gives **n°** and **N°**. It looks like the famous perfume named **N° 5** uses a degree sign:

[image]

Doing it is however sometimes considered incorrect because the degree sign is technically a small zero while the upper *o* is the vowel ending the word *numéro*. Using the degree sign also makes the plural unaesthetic to say the least: **n°ˢ** or **n°<sup>s</sup>**.

To get a consistent display, you then need to use a superscript "o", possibly followed by a superscript "s" if plural:

*Numéro*: HTML: **n<sup>o</sup>** or **N<sup>o</sup>**, UTF-8: **nᵒ** or **Nᵒ**

*Numéros*: HTML: **n<sup>os</sup>** or **N<sup>os</sup>** and UTF-8: **nᵒˢ**  or **Nᵒˢ**.

Sometimes, the masculine ordinal glyph is used as in **nº** and **Nº**. It is not recommended because depending on the font used, the *o* might be underlined which is not a French thing, and there is no matching "s".

Similarly, the "Numero glyph" (**№**) is unused in French because the "o" is underlined and there are neither lowercase nor plural forms.

Capitalization follows the generic rule, if *numéro* is starting a sentence, the initial *N* should be in uppercase, otherwise, a lowercase *n* is used.

Note also that a space is required after **n<sup>o</sup>**, e.g.:

> **N<sup>o</sup> 4**

Answer (score 1):

Selon le « Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale » qui fait référence, on trouve dans la liste des abréviations :

[image]

soit :

- n° si on n'a qu'un numéro
- n°<sup>s</sup> si on liste plusieurs numéros. (Reste à savoir comment obtenir le « <sup>s</sup> ».

Answer (score 0):

From personnal experience, I have always seen people using "N°" or "n°" (both using DEGREE SIGN U+00B0) written by hand, on computer or printed in books/newspapers.